# Why is python sphinx failing due to sys import?

Tags: python, docker, python-sphinx

I'm running unit tests with docker and a Makefile, and the last step is to compile documentation with

```
python setup.py build_sphinx
```

which is failing with the error message `ERROR: InvocationError for command python setup.py build_sphinx (exited with code -11 (SIGSEGV)) (exited with code -11)`.

I went through all my code and found that the issue is importing `sys`.
If I change

```
import datetime
import functools
import json
import logging
import sys
```

to

```
import datetime
import functools
import json
import logging
# import sys
```

then I don't get this error anymore. I don't understand what is happening. I have `sys` in other files and didn't get this issue with those imports.

Comment: SIGSEGV means something dereferenced an invalid pointer -- it's not supposed to be able to happen at all (when you aren't using C libraries / `ctypes` / etc), and generally means something broke in a surprising and unusual way. Attaching gdb to your Python interpreter and getting a backtrace (after installing any debug symbol packages your distro offers for the Python interpreter itself) is a good place to start in running it down.

Comment: Long ago, btw, when bad RAM was a lot more common, it was not unheard of to see a segfault happen only when a certain amount of memory was already in use, or a system was under a certain amount of load / above a certain temperature / otherwise in conditions that led to a hardware fault. That's not something I've seen so often in recent decades, though; starting with gdb is by far the better bet than pulling out memtest86 or such.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to get an answer here, as opposed to just _suggestions_, I'd suggest trying to reproduce the problem in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/; once you have a reproducer that can be run on different hardware to cause the same problem, people who aren't you will be able to dig into it. Unfortunately, that might be a difficult thing to do; it's not uncommon for a segfault in the Python interpreter to be distro-, environment-, or hardware-specific.

Comment: (if it _is_ distro-specific and can't be reproduced on repl.it (which is NixOS-based), a Dockerfile with a base image from the distro it does happen on might be the way to go for a reproducer others can run)